# How to manage complex layout in android, Nested layout in android or should implement fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-linearlayout

I want to create android layout like this.
[image]

So i create Linear layout and used weight sum.
My layout is so big and confusing sometimes and in java code i am inflating other layout also.
Does anyone suggest me better way to create exact same layout without creating so much layout.
can i use fragments? if yes how to manage all different different fragments into one layout?
This is my Linearlayout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="8" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/welcome_tv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#fafbfc"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Bienvenu, Swap ! \nVous avez 32 nouvelles offers et 1 alerte."
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:background="#f2f3f3"
   >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bt1"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_button_green"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:text="32"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="40sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:text="Offer vous\nCorrespondent" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bt2"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_button_yellow"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:text="7"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="40sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Offer\npostulees" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bt3"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_button_blue"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:text="19"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="40sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tagline_tv2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Offer\nsauvgardees" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/dashboard_rdv_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:background="#F29779"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/rdv_layout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/person_name_tv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="RDV avec John Smith"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rdv_type_tv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="Entretien telephonique"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rdv_phone_tv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="tel: 06 06 06 060 06"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="2" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/dashboard_article_layout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/dashboard_graph_layout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

On Small screen it look like this..
texview gone under button and meeting alert time and date does not look good any idea to manage small screen. currently i have only one default folder of Layout.
[image]

Comment: You could do everything with TextViews (yes, no buttons, no ImageViews). As per my preferences, I'd use RelativeLayouts as containers. And would possibly take advantage of including external layouts.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein thank you for suggestion.. as per you said i can use textview having color background and circle style is that right?...also my question is i am not using fragments i have create this layout using linear one and at run time i inflate bottom article and pie chart layout So is it right way to do it?

Comment: Yes, it's only images and text, after all. You could use compound drawables to inflate the images at the top (they'll be horizontally centered) of the TextViews. (use `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds()`)

Comment: @FrankN.Stein thank you i edit my question..same screen does not look good in small screen device.you can take a look new picture added...can you please tell me how can i manage different screen size in honeycomb and later android version? (in old version there was layout-small, layout-large, layout-xtralarge but it won't work after v2.3)

Comment: Personally, I don't use such folders. I prefer drawable-ldpi, ..., drawable-xxxhdpi.

Comment: The smaller design just seems to need a fix to the calendar on the orange banner. It also doesn't have the offers (I guess it's by design?).

Comment: @FrankN.Stein thank you so much...I am new to development and i want to improve my android UI skills so can you suggest any blog or book other than android blog/fourm.

Comment: Vaste argument... I could suggest you to follow `Lars Vogel` and `Romain Guy`, just to name a couple (and `Android Hive`, just to name another just popped in my mind right now). Google always remains your best friend. As a **golden rule**, the less layouts and Views you use, the better performances you get. And this is true **always**. Since a TextView is clickable and can contain images (background + up to 4 compound drawables), it's a real **jolly**. By images I mean drawables, all sorts of.